# How can I exclude a specific string from from python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to parse `/etc/mtab` but exclude `/boot`. I thought perhaps non-capturing groups would be the way to go, but it doesn't work as I expected. This is the regex I constructed:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", server, "cat", mtab],stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
  fsMatch = re.search(r'([\w/:]+) (/([\w/:-]+)|(?:boot)) (nfs|ext3)', line)
  if fsMatch:
    print fsMatch.group(1,2,4)
```

Output:

```
('/dev/sda1', '/boot', 'ext3')
('/dev/mapper/foo1', '/export/foo1', 'ext3')
('/dev/mapper/foo2', '/export/foo2', 'ext3')
('/dev/mapper/foo3', '/export/foo3', 'ext3')
('/dev/mapper/foo4', '/export/foo4', 'ext3')
('/dev/mapper/foo5', '/export/foo5', 'ext3')
('servernfs:/install', '/mnt', 'nfs')
```

I'm pretty confident the `|` is wrong (and obviously more is wrong) but have hit a roadblock.

I'm looking for all matches for `/[\w/:-]+` but exclude matches to `/boot`

Suggestions?

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at excluding things. Do it in a separate check.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a negative lookbehind or negative lookahead, described [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions.html) with a hint below:

```
r'^(?!/boot).*$'
```

If you need to capture that 'servernfs:' one and not 'servernfs:/boot', you'll need to sprinkle in a little '|' and '([a-z]+:)' somewhere at the top (after the '^')

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude the line:

```
for line in proc.stdout:
  if 'boot' not in line:
      # the rest
```

However, since `mtab` is delimited on space, you can just use `split`:

```
>>> with open('foo.txt') as f:
...     lines = [line.split(' ') for line in f if 'boot' not in line]
...
```

Comment: It'd make more sense for that check to go on the `if fsMatch` line wouldn't it? eg:`if fsMatch and not fsMatch.group(2).startswith('/boot')` ?

Comment: Yea, the startswith is key. But then you've got the `fs:/boot` matching problem.

Comment: paths like /home/user/bin/reboot will be rejected by the `'boot' not in line` filter, I think. And '/boot' doesn't fix it either without the startswith bit. I like Jon Clements approach. Let's the regex do the heavy lifting of a match and startswith does the simple, precise exclude.